# Mule Web Service Consumer Warning : Operation Messages With More then 1 Part Are Not Supported

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Web Service Consumer and i was trying to call operation with Multiple Parameters it is warning me that

`Warning : Operation Messages With More then 1 Part Are Not Supported`

I just want to pass multiple parameters to access my SOAP method to achieve the task.

Is this the problem with Web Service Consumer or is their any way to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a known limitation of the web services consumer. However you can accomplish this with the [cxf component](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/CXF+Module+Reference).

Comment: oh waiting for Mule to resolve this i am posting this issue in Mule Jira make sure to be marked it as a enhancement. http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/mule-web-service-consumer-warning-operation-messages-with-more-then-1-part-are-not-supported

Comment: I have added a answer with some additional information, would be great if you could have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I having the same issue and found some information around it ...

There is a improvement logged in [JIRA](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8147), may help if you vote for it :)

This [link](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/warning-operation-messages-with-more-than-1-part-are-not-supported) suggests that you can still use WSConsumer but need to do some hand crafting of the request XML ... I could not understand what that exactly it meant so if anyone has an example on it would be great

PS: The problem I had with using CXF component is that it does not play well with the new Dataweave transformer as the Dataweave needs to be placed within the response block and from there it cannot datasense the response coming out from the CXF component

Answer (score 0):

The Solution here is very simple. **You just have to comment other messages  and then load metadata for non-commented message (for one which you're trying to load metadata). Repeat this procedure for all the other messages and you're good to go.** 
Hope this helps !